How to efficiently mirror Topics with different QoS Policies?
I’m trying to access ROS2 data from Carnegie Robotics’ S27 Camera (product, docs). The S27 publishes Messages with Best Effort Reliability and Volatile Durability. I’m using ROS2 Foxy on Ubuntu 20.04.
I’m using the application RTMaps to subscribe to the S27’s Topics. RTMaps’ built-in subscriber only supports Reliable Reliability and Transient Local Durability, however, so it isn't able to subscribe directly to the S27.
My current solution for subscribing to S27 Topics with RTMaps is to mirror the S27 Topics with my own nodes, written in Python, which subscribe to the S27 Topic and re-publish that Topic with the correct QoS Policies for RTMaps.
Here's some of my mirror node code:
def __init__(self, relative_topic: str, topic_message_type):
    self.subscription = self.create_subscription(
        self.message_type,
        self.s27_topic,
        self.subscriber_callback,
        qos_profile=self.s27_qos,)

    self.publisher = self.create_publisher(
        self.message_type, self.mirror_topic, qos_profile=self.rtmaps_qos)

def subscriber_callback(self, msg):
    self.publisher.publish(msg)

where s27_qos and rtmaps_qos are the correct QoSProfiles.
Is this a good solution? Does ROS already support this QoS mirror functionality? I’m still a beginner. Are there Best Practices for mirroring nodes?
Thank you.
